# The type initializer for 'PublicDomain.TzTimeZone' threw an exception

Tags: .net, timezone

hi i am getting This problem - type initializer for 'PublicDomain.TzTimeZone' threw an exception. with .net please tell me why this is and how to solve this?

thanks

inner exception is "Cannot find time zone with UTC offset -12:00:00."

Answer (score 1):

Well, we don't know what that type is... (presumably the code from [here](http://publicdomain.codeplex.com)) but my *guess* is that it's missing a file with time zone data in, or something similar.

The exception should have an InnerException which will give more information about what went wrong. Hopefully that will help you solve it.

Comment: hi thanks ,inner exception is "Cannot find time zone with UTC offset -12:00:00." please tell me why does it comes and how does i solve it

Comment: @Hema: I strongly suspect it's because the project hasn't kept up with the latest time zone information. Do you have the latest source and the latest files for it? You may want to grab the source and debug into it...